# Error in ImageButtons at src:"@drawable/..." Top level element is not completed

Tags: android, xml, layout, drawable, imagebutton

Everytime I put a @drawable item it appears underlined in red. It worked before but I pressed one of the options in the light bulb that appears next to the line and then all drawables became errors. I can't find the problem... I'm working with Android Studio. I tried to rebuild, clean, reimport... and nothing solves the problem.

My code:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"  android:stretchColumns="*" android:background="#ffffff">


    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/backstate" /> /////////////////ERROR in "@drawable/backstate" (Underlined in red)

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/blanc"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/blancstate"/> /////////////////SAME ERROR 

        <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/groc"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/grocstate"/> /////////////////SAME ERROR

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/taronja"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/taronjastate"/> /////////////////SAME ERROR

        <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/vermell"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/vermellstate"/> /////////////////SAME ERROR

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

All xml states are correct, layouts are well formed, i didn't change anything from the code, and by clicking that option that I didn't remember, all drawables started to give me errors.

**ERROR DESCRIPTION:** Top level element is not completed. Valid XML document must have a root tag.

Anyway the document is well formed... And it says the same error each time I write "@drawable/..."

EDIT: **I found the origin of the problem.** android namespace is the problem, if I change it for tools namespace it works. tools:src="@drawable/vermellstate" for example.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Does Image **Exists** ??

Comment: Yes of course, Images are in a folder called drawable-sw480dp and layouts in a folder named layout-sw480dp. States and images are in the same folder. And it was working until I press that option... The way is that I start another project from 0 and I copy the code of the old one, the problem persists.

Comment: Are you getting this message on mouse click `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/backstate').` ?

Comment: Yes at first, now it doesn't appear more. But maybe still happens.

Comment: Does the app still work and display correctly despite this or does it actually give you an exception when you run it?

Comment: The app still display the buttons, sorry I forgot to say that. The app find the buttons and display it properly, the problem is that now I can't try it on my device. I can't run it.

Comment: The problem is android namespace that don't let me use src atributte. Why?

Comment: have u tried android:background="@drawable/image" instead of "src"?

Comment: The problem is the namespace, it's not the same.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Select item that is displaying error, then press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> on the drawable item which calls error (for example:"@drawable/vermellstate")  and select **"Uninject language/reference"**

Answer (score 1):

Could be the case that you injected language by mistake.
If you  are using Android Studio **right click the code in question then->Local History->Show History** and revert to a time prior to "Language Injection Configuration Update" .

Hope it helped, 
Best of luck !